# Emacs Tpu-edt emulation scrolling margins startup

Tags: emacs, scroll, emulation, edt

Can anyone help me get scrolling margins enabled automatically when I start emacs with tpu-edt emulation? 
Currently, my _emacs file (WinXP) contains the line:

```
(setq term-setup-hook 'tpu-edt-on)
```

I find TPU works great, and I can manually supply the command

```
M-x tpu-set-scroll-margin
```

It then prompts me for the top and bottom parameters, and works fine when I supply them.
I tried adding the example line from the tpu-extras.el file into the _emacs file:

```
(tpu-set-scroll-margins "10%" "15%")
```

but I get the message:
**Symbol's function definition is void: tpu-set-scroll-margin**

Help!  Scrolling margins are the best feature of all time, and I want them always on!

Comment: Is it just a typo in your question that in one instance you're using `tpu-set-scroll-margin` and in the other, `tpu-set-scroll-margins` with a trailing 's'?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the typo question raised by @sanityinc (still open --- you cite the name without `s` twice and with `s` once), it's likely that you need to invoke that code when you are in the proper mode. For example, if the mode in question is named `tpu-edt-mode`, then you do do something like this:

```
(add-hook 'tpu-edt-mode (lambda () (tpu-set-scroll-margins "10%" "15%")))
```